# How do i check if TcpClient is connected?

Tags: .net, tcpclient

When my client app closes the socket or even terminates my server still thinks its alive. I even check [TcpClient.Connected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connected%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) then i see this. I bolded the important part

> true if the Client socket was connected to a remote resource **as of the most recent operation**; otherwise, false.

How do i know if the socket is closed or not? At the moment I have to do an operation and get an exception to discover if its opened or close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many things that can break communications over a socket, many of which are totally outside your control, best keep it simple.

At the moment you have a perfectly acceptable detection mechanism, dead simple and low cost.

You could do a heart beat, send an I'm here message from the client every X somethings, and then have the server run through and see if there hadn't been one for X * fiddle factor intervals. Uses processor time and bandwidth though.

Another option depends on your client detecting it's no longer connected and requesting a new connection. If you have a unique identifier in the request , you can run through your existing connections for it, kill it, if it's there, and start then continue as normal.

I know exception doesn't feel right, but it's only really a problem if you keep losing the connection, and if you were your efforts would be better directed at sorting that out.