# Tcpclient not connecting

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient

I am trying to run a Tcpclient to a Switch but I am having difficulties.
I have a code that just connect to the IP and tells me if it connect successfully or not. Problem is it doesn't tell me anything.

Code is as follows:

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Text

Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim myTcpClient As New TcpClient()
    Try
        myTcpClient.Connect(IP address, 23)
    Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Catch ex As SocketException
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I am trying to make a Application that allows the user to change the Vlans on a switch automatically, so any other suggestion would help.

Comment: Just add after connection : 
Console.WriteLine("connected ? : {0}", myTcpClient.Connected) ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the overload you are using `myTcpClient.Connect(IP address, 23)` it connects the client to a remote TCP host using the specified IP address and port number. Are you sure that host (TcpListener) is listening and up? Is the port opened, these kind of little mistakes need to be checked first. If not any of thoses...

[**Here's**](http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20020323.asp) a great link doing exactly what you are wanting, I hope you find it useful.

***On another note....***

> There are so many things that can break communications over a socket, many of which are totally outside your control, best keep it simple.
>
> You could do a heart beat, send an I'm here message from the client every X somethings, and then have the server run through and see if there hadn't been one for X * fiddle factor intervals. Uses processor time and bandwidth though.
>
> Another option depends on your client detecting it's no longer connected and requesting a new connection. If you have a unique identifier in the request , you can run through your existing connections for it, kill it, if it's there, and start then continue as normal.

Referenced from [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117373/how-do-i-check-if-tcpclient-is-connected)...

Comment: ...Noob question: Is TCPListener really required?  I just want to issue commands to the Switch or Switches to change the Vlans with using CMD.exe or Sendkeys. Everything seems to be pointing at sockets.